# How to get Parameterized routes working

Tags: routes, aurelia, url-parameters

I'm probably just missing something obvious, but i can't get either `:id` or `*id` to work.

This is the routing configs I'm using:

```
{
  route: 'char/:id',
  name: 'char',
  moduleId: 'modules/char/char',
  href: "char"
}
```

And this is the code i got in `char.ts`:

```
export class Char {
  activate(params: {id: string}) {
    console.log(params.id);
  }
}
```

Now i cant seem to assign values to `id` from the address bar.
What is the syntax for this?

(also I've tried making the parameter optional, with `:id?` and still nothing)

Comment: Your route is fine what do you have if you only console.log(params)? Is it undefined?

Comment: @maximedubois no it wont log anything either way.
If i navigate to `http://localhost:9000/char` with the route set to `'char/:id?`
i get redirected to the home page. While if i navigate to `http://localhost:9000/char/` i get 404.
And if i provide a value `http://localhost:9000/char/?id=42` i get a 404 on the `vendor-bundle.js` script.

Comment: @maximedubois nvm... I'm new to singlepage frameworks, didn't know i had to put an # in front of the route name in the url. 
Thanks any :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out i had it a bit backwards from the start. 
This is what works:

```
http://localhost:9000/#char/foobar
```

then `id` would be equal to `foobar`.